# extending chart class in extjs4 mvc framework results in "config is undefined"

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to extend the chart class to use in a view as part of the extjs4 MVC framework. I get this error in firebug:

```
config is undefined 
[Break On This Error] me.initTheme(config.theme || me.theme);
Chart....8936564 (line 191)
```

This is the class definition:

```
Ext.define('CDR.chart.Daily', {
alias: 'widget.dailychart',
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',    
initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        id: 'daily',
        insetPadding: 30,

     ... irrelevant code cut .......

    });          
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

This is the view class the chart is added to:

```
Ext.define('CDR.view.trunk.View', {
alias: 'widget.trunkview',
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',    
requires: [
    'CDR.chart.Daily'
],        
initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        id        : 'itemCt',
        border    : false,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: {
            type : 'hbox',
        },            
        items: [
            Ext.create('CDR.chart.Daily'),
            {
                id    : 'contentCt',
                width : 500,
                border: false
            }
        ]
    });                
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }    
});
```

Comment: Can you post your full `CDR.chart.Daily` definition please?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug, because 'theme' should be with a 'Base' value by default, but hasn't.
From source code of Chart.js :

```
/**
 * @cfg {String} theme (optional) The name of the theme to be used. A theme defines the colors and
 * other visual displays of tick marks on axis, text, title text, line colors, marker colors and styles, etc.
 * Possible theme values are 'Base', 'Green', 'Sky', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Blue', 'Yellow' and also six category themes
 * 'Category1' to 'Category6'. Default value is 'Base'.
 */
```

So, just add following code into your new class:

```
constructor: function() {
    this.callParent([{theme: 'Category1'}]);
},
```

It's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem but not for the config object but for the Base Theme , for your issue first you can correct the items property of your panel instead of

```
 items: [
        Ext.create('CDR.chart.Daily'),
```

it should be

items: [
           { Ext.create('CDR.chart.Daily'),....}

Also if you are using the MVC framework then make sure in your app.js you  have added the below lines in the Ext.require section :

```
'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
'Ext.chart.theme.Theme',
```